# Convert this to a regular for loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, foreach

I have this code and want to turn it from a for each loop to a regular for loop

```
for(Coordinate neighbors : getNeighbors(current)){
    if(!previous.containsKey(neighbors)){
         previous.put(neighbors, current);
         list.add(neighbors);
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad specification. getNeighbors returns a Set of Coordinates

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: This is impossible to answer, as we have no idea what the type of `getNeighbors(current)` is.

Comment: If `getNeighbours` returns a `Set<Coordinate>` then Eran's answer will work, but I don't know why you don't like the for each loop.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to give the best answer without knowing what type `getNeighbors(current)` returns, but you can always create a for loop with an explicit iterator :

```
for(Iterator<Coordinate> iter = getNeighbors(current).iterator(); iter.hasNext();){
    Coordinates neighbors = iter.next();
    if(!previous.containsKey(neighbors)){
        previous.put(neighbors, current);
        list.add(neighbors);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Current is of type Coordinate which consists of two integers
GetNeighbors returns a set

Answer (score 1):

Without reasonable explanation of what you're doing I can't provide a better answer than this, but it gives the picture.

In case of array

```
for(int i=0; i<getNeighbors(current).length; i++){
    if(!previous.containsKey(getNeighbors(current)[i])){
        previous.put(getNeighbors(current)[i], current);
        list.add(getNeighbors(current)[i]);
    }
}
```

In case of ArrayList

```
for(int i=0; i<getNeighbors(current).size(); i++){
    if(!previous.containsKey(getNeighbors(current).get(i))){
        previous.put(getNeighbors(current).get(i), current);
        list.add(getNeighbors(current).get());
    }
}
```